# google.visualization.DataTable: Object new Date( 2013, 12, 14, 19, 53, 31, 0 ) has no method 'getTime'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the code that should draw a chart, and another php script is sending it the json string. For some reason the Date object is not created, Am I using the wrong json string?

This is the code:

```
<script>
  var jsonData = $.ajax({ 
  url: "get_stat_data.php?ID=2811&CMD=watts", 
  dataType:"json", 
  async: false 
}).responseText;     

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
  function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);    
    var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
    document.getElementById('visualization'));
    annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true});
  }
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

The json string:

```
{ "cols": [{"id":"0","label":"Time","type":"date"},{"id":"1","label":"Watts","type":"number"}], "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"new Date( 2013, 12, 14, 19, 53, 31, 0 )"},{"v":"109"}]},{"c":[{"v":"new Date( 2013, 12, 14, 19, 53, 31, 0 )"},{"v":"107"}]},{"c":[{"v":"new Date( 2013, 12, 14, 19, 53, 32, 0 )"},{"v":"109"}]}]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the "new Date()".

Comment: That's not valid json. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/838733 for a proper example on how to handle dates.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the `responseText` to your data variable which is just a string - even if you were to parse it yourself the dates are still strings which the Google API doesn't seem to resolve automatically.  Without reading too much into it *(that's your job...)* you should ideally change your back-end code to pass the date string in an [*RFC-2822*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) compliant format that can be parsed easily by the Javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

For now, I've just added a workaround - technically ***if you trust the source*** of the data you could `eval` the code but fearful of down votes I've opted for a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) instead.  I've also tweaked the logic a little bit because frankly I can't bring myself to post a synchronous *AJAX* solution.

```js
myVis = {
    data: {},
    googLoaded: false,
    dataLoaded: false,
    drawVisualization: function(){ 
        if(!this.googLoaded || !this.dataLoaded) return;
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(this.data),    
            line = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
                document.getElementById('visualization')
            );
        line.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true});
    },
    dateFromArgs: function($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7){
        return new Date($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7); // fugly
    }
};
```

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'get_stat_data.php?ID=2811&CMD=watts',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        $.each(json.rows, function(i, el){
            var args = el.c[0].v.match(/(\d+)/g);
            el.c[0].v = myVis.dateFromArgs.apply(null, args);
        });
        myVis.data = json;
        myVis.dataLoaded = true;
        myVis.drawVisualization();
    }
});
```

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { 
    packages: ['annotatedtimeline'],
    callback: function(){
        myVis.googLoaded = true;
        myVis.drawVisualization();
    }
});
```

<sup>*Note:* You can put this in a single `<script></script>` block - it's just separated above to avoid scrollbars.</sup>

[**jsFiddle: demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nRjnX/1/)

---

The graph looks a little sparse to me - I'm not sure if this resembles what you were looking for or if you've just given us a limited dataset to work with but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.